# Contour and Html.Action crashing "Cannot redirect from a Child Action"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, contour

I am have an Umbraco 7 MVC website running Contour. I have two contour forms on the page running smoothly with no errors. I created a Login form using the surface controller and now when any contour form is submitted it gets the error below:

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot redirect from a Child Action
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot redirect from a Child Action

Source Error:


Line 404:
Line 405:            <div class="lg-details">
Line 406:                @Html.Action("MemberLogin", "MemberLoginSurface")
```

As you can see I call the surface controller using @Html.Action(). Any help on solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
**Controller code being used**

```
public class MemberLoginModel
{

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

public class MemberLoginSurfaceController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("MemberLogin")]
    public ActionResult MemberLoginGet()
    {
        return PartialView("MemberLogin", new MemberLoginModel());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MemberLogout()
    {
        Session.Clear();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return Redirect("/");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("MemberLogin")]
    public ActionResult MemberLoginPost(MemberLoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect("/extranet/");
                }
                else
                {
                    return Redirect("/extranet/");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Status"] = "Invalid username or password";
                return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
            }
        }

        TempData["Status"] = "Invalid request";
        return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
}
```

**calling Contour form using**

```
  @Umbraco.RenderMacro("umbracoContour.RazorRenderForm", new { FormGuid = "a6362c56-a7d7-41dd-b4c9-61ea28d420f6" })
```

Thanks
Maxi

Comment: Show some more code. Controller code

Comment: @Farzi Updated the question to show both code and how I called the contour form. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, fixed this. Thought I would answer for anyone who has this issue in the future.

On page load it retrieve the HttpGet for @Html.Action("MemberLogin", "MemberLoginSurface")

```
 [HttpGet]
[ActionName("MemberLogin")]
public ActionResult MemberLoginGet()
{
    return PartialView("MemberLogin", new MemberLoginModel());
}
```

However, when submitting contour it becomes a POST and attempts to run the code for HttpPost:

```
  [HttpPost]
[ActionName("MemberLogin")]
public ActionResult MemberLoginPost(MemberLoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect("/extranet/");
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/extranet/");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Status"] = "Invalid username or password";
            return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
        }
    }

    TempData["Status"] = "Invalid request";
    return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
}
```

Since ModelState.IsValid IS NOT valid it tries to redirect causing the error. I had a partial view calling the form layout and what to use.

```
 using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("MemberLogin", "MemberLoginSurface"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Username)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Username)

    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(x => Model.Password)

    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.RememberMe)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.RememberMe)
 <input type="submit" id="btnLogin" name="btnLogin" />
 }
```

Changing both the **[HttpPost] [ActionName("MemberLogin")]** and 
**using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("btnLogin", "MemberLoginSurface"))** to use btnLogin instead.

For some reason, when posting the contour form, even though it uses different parameters, controllers and actionName the MemberLogin attempts to run as HttpPost.

Hopefully if anyone else finds this an issue then this will help.

Comment: Hi @maxi, can you elaborate your answer more? I can't completely understand how you resolved the issue. thanks